# Escreva uma função: int solution(int A[], int N);

Tags: python

Meu professor me deu esse problema mas não estou conseguindo fazer

```
int solution(int A[], int N);
```

que, dada uma matriz A de N inteiros, retorna o menor inteiro positivo (maior que 0) que não ocorre em A.

Por exemplo,

- Dado `A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]`, a função deve retornar 5;
- Para outro exemplo, dado `A = [1, 2, 3]`, a função deve retornar 4;
- Dado `A = [-1, -3]`, a função deve retornar 1;

Assuma que:

- N é um número inteiro dentro do intervalo [1..100,000];
- Cada elemento da matriz A é um número inteiro dentro do intervalo [-1,000,000 ... 1,000,000].

Os elementos das matrizes de entrada podem ser modificados.

Tentei usando o `not in list`, mas não estou conseguindo formular

```
a =(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2)
limite = max(a)

for i in a:
    if (i >=0 and i not in a and a <= limite):
        b = i;
        print(b)
```

Comment: Mas se você percorre `i in a`, concorda que não faz sentido verificar se `i not in a`, visto que sempre `i` estará em `a`? Aliás, tem certeza que isso deverá ser em Python? Pela cabeçalho dado, está mais para C.

Comment: Eita, agora que percebi isso. será que eu consigo fazer uma operação ternaria?

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso, basta você iniciar uma variável, `i`, em 1, verificar se ela não está em `A`; se estiver, retornar `i`, caso contrário incrementar `i` e continuar até a condição ser verdadeira:

```
def solution(A, N) -> int:
    i = 1
    while True:
        if i not in A:
            return i
        i += 1
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WellinformedWordyObservatory) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/cZ4h6w) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/ca8c59227400c71e47209a9d777548fb)</sup>

Alternativamente, você pode utilizar a função `itertools.count` que já implementa esta lógica:

```
from itertools import count

def solution(A, N) -> int:
    for i in count(1):
        if i not in A:
            return i
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TintedScrawnyClicks) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/m1C0qZ) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/7f923c56f5768f77ad401f073b4c7650)</sup>

> **Nota:** perceba que o parâmetro `N` é desnecessário para a implementação em Python, por isso suspeito que a intenção seja implementar isso em C - ou outra linguagem.